# Global js var unreadable in jQuery + $.ajax

Tags: jquery, json, var, populate

Morning all,

Im trying to populate a global var called `statusJson` before the `.ready()`, but for some reason can access and read the variable with the chrome console debug, but the script cant read the var.

The code: http://jsfiddle.net/wiitohzjeh/pEKyT/

As can see, the json info is obtained via `$.ajax` from a remote php file, i create a var simulating the ajax-json response, and commented the original `$.ajax` code.

The problem:
For some reason the chrome debug console return `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Thanks to all :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse JSON to object

Replace below:

```
statusJson = ajaxData;
```

With

```
statusJson = $.parseJSON(ajaxData);
```

And move `$(function(){ Status.init(); });` after `Status` definition

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/pEKyT/1/)

Comment: The response come parsed, i think. The original code is this: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=AVLkfwEz, modified as u say, the answer is the same `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined `

Comment: Updated, as u say. Still no works: http://jsfiddle.net/wiitohzjeh/pEKyT/2/, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined line :15`

Comment: `ajax call to statusjson.php` will not work in jsFiddle. Test locally and make sure response from `statusjson.php` is in `JSON` format

Comment: is JSON, `header("Content-type: application/json");`

Comment: Try `echo json_encode($response_data);` or `echo '{"status":["ok","allwork"],"statuses":{"login":true},"stream":{"1373877245":{"title":"asjdhfgjqwherh"}}}';`

Answer (score 0):

closure example of your code my friend :

```
var statusJson = {};

var Status =  new (function(){     

    // public function //
    function init(){        
    // this is the data returned by $.ajax:
    var ajaxData = '{"status":["ok","allwork"],"statuses":{"login":true},"stream":{"1373877245":{"title":"asjdhfgjqwherh"}}}';
        statusJson = $.parseJSON(ajaxData);
        this.updateHeader();  
    };

    // private function //
    function updateHeader(){
        $(".status-header span")
            .fadeOut()
            .addClass(statusJson.status[0])
            .text(statusJson.status[1])
            .fadeIn();
    };

    // return the PUBLIC functions //
    return {
        init: init
     };
})();

Status.init();
```

Comment: Nope, `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'updateHeader'` cant load `updateHeader()`, same with `Status.updateHeader`